# Displaying Array Using Custom Component

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I want to display a list of pictures in the following format using `react-admin`.

```
{
    "images": [
        {
            "created_at": "2021-03-17",
            "images": [
                {
                    "image": "http://url.com/img.jpeg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I can display the pictures using the following,

```
           <ArrayField source="images" label=''>
                <SingleFieldList>
                    <ArrayField source='images' label = '' sortable={false} >
                         <SingleFieldList>
                             <ImageField source='image' label = ''/>
                         </SingleFieldList>
                     </ArrayField>
                 </SingleFieldList>
             </ArrayField>
```

I would like to print these inside custom elements say each picture in a `div`. Reading through [1] and the docs [2] following example is provided,

```
const TagsField = ({ record }) => (
<ul>
    {record.tags.map(item => (
        <li key={item.name}>{item.name}</li>
    ))}
</ul>
)
TagsField.defaultProps = {
    addLabel: true
};
```

but there is not a complete example of how this component is used? How can i impelent a custom component to print the array?

[1] https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2383
[2] https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#arrayfield

Comment: Have you tried:
''
<ArrayField source='images.images' label = '' sortable={false} >
  <SingleFieldList>
    <ImageField source='image' label = ''/>
   </SingleFieldList>
 </ArrayField>
''